# Restrict access to pages to Facebook's OpenGraph scraper

Tags: .htaccess, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Is there some way to restrict access to one our pages to **only** allow Facebook's OpenGraph scraper system? We have multiple likes on one page (similar to Digg) and each 'like' needs its own OpenGraph tags which we have on separate pages via the page `story.php?1` and `?2` etc. We do not want the user to be able to view `story.php` as all they contain are the og: tags.

**EDIT:** It looks to be something I can do using the info in this post: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-move-a-url-via-301-redirect-and-retain-the-pages-facebook-likes-and-o

How can I exclude a particular domain from a HTTP 301 redirect. Can you help?

Comment: If you are talking about an Apache web server here, you can use mod_rewite – use a RewriteCond to check for the host name, and then redirect with a following RewriteRule.

Comment: I'm thinking of something like this, but instead of the IP it would be Facebook's domain... how would I add that? `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^173\.194\.41\.134
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php$
RewriteRule .* /index.php [R=302,L]`

Comment: Also instead of the root url it must only allow facebook.com to access story.php and deny everyone else.

Comment: Ah, that’s what you want – then you are on the wrong track here. Facebook’s scraper is the _client_ in this case, so the domain does not tell you what you want (because it’s _your_ domain). You can recognize the scraper by it’s User Agent header instead, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#scraperinfo

Comment: Exactly - you've got it. I have no idea how to put this together though unfortunately. So essentially ONLY `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php` should be allowed access to `story.php` and all other users are redirected to `index.php` - if that can be done I will be extremely happy!

Comment: Same principle as above – check User-Agent header with a RewriteCond, and redirect with a RewriteRule if not a match. Alternatively, you can also do it from within your PHP script (User-Agent is somewhere in $_SERVER, have a look), if that’s simpler to implement for you.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty clueless here - is there any possibility of you writing out the appropriate htaccess code? Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: There’s plenty of examples for mod_rewrite on the net – so please at least _try_ for yourself first. (Or, as I said, do it in PHP, if you’re more comfortable therein.)

Comment: I've a whole rack of mod_rewrites on the various websites we run but creating something new especially with this specific case is really not my 'thing'.

Comment: I guess the user agent is like this `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php` but specifying them to only have access `story.php` and everyone else to redirect to `index.php` is beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I opted to add this to the story.php PHP code and it works perfectly:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] != "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)") {
redirect('http://www.mywebsite.com', 302);
}
function redirect($url, $type=302) {
if ($type == 301) header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: $url");
die();
}

?>
```